# Troubles with threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading, network-programming, arp

I have been losing my sanity because I can't seem to figure out the following:
I have a simple scanner to identify other devices on the same network. Thanks to threading I can do this in parallel. When I grab the unique identifier of the hardware address of a responding device, I compare it to a csv file I have. This is all done within the same arp_scanner() function as can be seen below. I am aware that working with files within a threaded function is a very poor practice and I can see why in my terminal output.

I have tried to move this part out of the function but it requires the variable "vendor_address" which I can't get returned from the arp_scanner() function because it would require me to call it like `vendor_address = arp_scanner()` which would require the "target" parameter and overall run the function again.. right? I'm incredibly confused and tried loads of different things, even tried other poor practices such as the use of Global. I would very much appreciate advise on how to solve this issue so I can resume learning more.

Kind regards

```
from scapy.all import srp,Ether,ARP,conf
import socket
import scapy.all as scapy
import threading
import re
import csv
import queue


q = queue.Queue()

def get_ip():
    dev_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    dev_socket.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80)) 
    local_ip = str(dev_socket.getsockname()[0]) #Get local IP address
    base_ip = local_ip[:-3]
    ip_list = []
    for x in range(256): #Loop through subnet mask
        ip_list.append(base_ip + str(x))
    return(ip_list)

def arp_scanner(target):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=target)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    clients_list= []
    for element in answered_list:
        client_dict ={"Local IP": element[1].psrc, "mac": element[1].hwsrc}
        clients_list.append(client_dict)
        prep_string = str(clients_list).replace("[", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", "")  #Erase characters from the string
        print("----------------\n" + prep_string)
        hw_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:[0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}') #Regular expression to define hardware address(format)
        hw_address = str(re.findall(hw_pattern, prep_string)).replace("[", "").replace("'", "").replace("]", "") #Select hardware address from string
        vendor_address = hw_address[0:8] #Only grab Organizational Unique Identifier
        with open('mac-vendors.csv', 'rt') as csv_file: 
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
                if vendor_address.upper() in row[0]: #Match Unique identifier against vendor csv
                    print(row[1] + "\n----------------")
                else:
                    pass

ip_list = get_ip()

for item in ip_list: #Put IP addresses in queue
    q.put(item)

for item in q.queue:
    t = threading.Thread(target=arp_scanner, args=(item,)) #ARP_scanner function but threaded
    t.start()
```

Comment: Your description doesn't actually state what the problem is. You say "I can see why in my terminal output" but show us an example of the output or what is wrong/unexpected about the output. Also, other than being horribly inefficient the way you've structured the code, there isn't anything wrong with reading the CSV file as you're doing in your example.

Comment: Ugh! My previous comment should have said "but **do not** show us an example of the output or **explain** what is wrong/unexpected about the output."